# cannnot GET pdf file on new tab

Tags: javascript, pdf, vuejs2

I'm working on a Vue.js project and I want to display a PDF file on new tab when I click to a certain link.

I have this directory and I want to open *sample.pdf* (I'm working on *signUp.vue*):

[image]

I have this code in the HTML part, the link I can use to open the said file.

```
<a v-on:click="showTaC">Terms and Conditions</a>
```

and here's the `showTaC` function:

```
showTaC: function(){
  var pdf = '../assets/sample.pdf';
  window.open(pdf);
}
```

when I click the link, it opens to a new tab but it's a blank page and says *Cannot GET /assets/sample.pdf*

Where did I went wrong? I'm pretty sure my url directory is correct. Maybe I need to make a new route for this? Does the number of page matters?

How do I make this work?

Comment: see if your pdf url opens or not, from address bar

Comment: I would check if your url is correct, for example try to replace the relative url to the absolute one, and check if it works. Also check if your browser have some PDF plugin, to be sure, that it can open pdf at least.

Comment: also try `var pdf = '/assets/sample.pdf';` remove dots

Comment: @ShishirArora tried it. didn't work. sorry.

Comment: @ShishirArora thanks for the idea of opening the pdf through the browser. Because of that I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED IT!

thanks for @ShishirArora for giving me the idea of opening the file through my browser. Because of that I figured out what url I need to store by examining the url on the address bar when I opened the pdf.

I replaced the url with:

`var pdf = '/src/assets/sample.pdf'`